# Facebook PHP SDK: Uncaught OAuthException: This authorization code has been used

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following sections of code to try and authenticate against Facebook using the official PHP SDK:

```
public function get_login_url() {
    $login = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_stream, email, publish_actions','redirect_uri' => 'http://www.sociaspire.com/lib/ajax/facebook-callback.php'));
    return $login;
}

public function get_access_token($auth_code) {
    $token_request_params = array(
    'client_id' => $this->app_id,
    'redirect_uri' => "http://www.sociaspire.com/lib/ajax/facebook-callback.php",
    'client_secret' => $this->app_key,
    'code' => $auth_code,
    );

    $token_request = $this->facebook->api('oauth/access_token?','GET',$token_request_params);
}
```

My flow is such that I call get_login_url, navigate to that URL and I am then redirected back to my callback URL, where I should be able to exchange the code Facebook gives for a (short-lived) access token, however when I attempt to get the access token, the API throws:

```
OAuthException: This authorization code has been used
```

I'm not sure why, as I haven't made any other requests with the code.

If anybody could help I would be grateful!

Comment: Hm, are you sure you're only calling `get_access_token()` once?

Comment: What essentially happens is that the Facebook callback URI returns to a page that then uses the code from the get request to call the method get_access_token() , so I can't think why this page would be loaded more than once.

Comment: Would there be an easy way to check if the method is called twice on the same page load?

Comment: Why are you fetching the access token with the graph api? Why don't you just do this `$this->facebook->getAccessToken();`

Comment: I was under the impression getAccessToken() gets the currently set access token, but I'll give it a go!

Comment: getAccessToken() gets the token for the current user session.

Comment: Ah that seems to work, thanks! But doesn't that make the `code` parameter the login URL returns redundant?

Comment: @BnMcG Didn't check, but `getAccessToken()` _may_ get the code from the current URL ($_GET).